# Without Header file how to call a function in other module using c++?

Tags: c++

I have a requirement without using header file how to create function prototype and how to use in other modules can you please explain how to do that.

Thanks in Advance.
Gunasekaran J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for an **extern** function?

It is more like C, not C++.
define a function in demo1.cpp:

```
void printXX(){ cout << "call me !"; }
```

And then in demo2.cpp:

```
extern void printXX();
```

Comment: The `extern` keyword is optional in this case.   The only requirement is that a declaration of the function be visible to the compiler before an attempt to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Header files are basically inserted to the code, if you `#include` them. If you have `header.h` which contains the following:

```cpp
void someFunction();
```

and have `module.cpp` which contains this:

```cpp
#include "header.h"

void moduleFunction() {
    someFunction();
}
```

then the header file's contents are copied to the place of `include`. After preprocessing, `module.cpp` will look like this:

```cpp
void someFunction();

void moduleFunction() {
    someFunction();
}
```

So you just need to place the function declarations inside the `.cpp` file.